# Were there other reasons or interests apart from Pan-Slavism for the Russian Empire to support Serbia?

Tags: world-war-one, russia, austria-hungary, serbia

In my History class, I was taught that that the Russian Empire supported Serbia's independence and nationality and fought against the Austria-Hungary Empire due to Pan-Slavism. My point is, were there any other interests Russia had in Serbia or around the region because I don't think it's only because of Pan-Slavism?

> *Pan-Slavism, a movement which crystallized in the mid-19th century, is the political ideology concerned with the advancement of integrity and unity for the Slavic-speaking peoples. Its main impact occurred in the Balkans, where non-Slavic empires had ruled the South Slavs for centuries. These were mainly the Byzantine Empire, Austria-Hungary (both as separate entities for most of the period), the Ottoman Empire, and Venice.*

- [Wikipedia: Pan-Slavism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-Slavism)

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the guidance in our [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: I would argue that pan-slavism was in fact the pretext for a whole bunch of reasons for Russia to support Serbia, and generaly slavic countries in the region. The answer is in your question really. Non slavic rival empires, lorded over slavic nations. What better way to destabilize them than with some good propaganda and create satellite countries friendly towards your interests?

Comment: Question is not bad, but it would take a while to write down good answer - motivation was ranging from cold Russian interests to pure emotions and spirituality ;)